# How to wait for the ftp request finished, then continue the programm

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I use "SimpleFTPSample" to do a ftp request for listing the derictory info. Part of the code is as below:

```
- (void)_startReceive
{
 ......
    self.networkStream = (NSInputStream *) ftpStream;
    self.networkStream.delegate = self;
    [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIMEOUTFTP target:self
                                   selector:@selector(dealTimeOut:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
 ......
}
```

I also set a NSTimer to stop the networkStream after TIMEOUTFTP, the networkStream will also be closed if the request is finished correctly within TIMEOUTFTP that I define. I use the method in another place like this:

```
- (void)downLoadData
{
    NSArray* receivedData;
    [ftpService _startReceive];

   //wait until the network is closed
    while (ftpService.isReceiving) {}

    receivedData = ftpService.dataArray;

    if([receivedData count] == 0) {
       NSLog(@"no data get");   
    }
    else {
       NSLog(@"get data number %d", [receivedData count]);
    }
```

}

The situation is that the program stuck at "while (ftpService.isReceiving) {}". I am not familiar with Multiple Thread. May be I do not understand the run loop correctly. Can someone tell me why this happen and how to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reconsider whether you really want to wait for the received data before letting the program proceed.  Instead, you should put your UI into a state where it shows that it's downloading and restricts what the user can do, return control to the app's main event loop, and let it call your delegate method when data is received.  Only once the data is received should you unlock the UI and proceed to the next step, whatever that is.

Blocking the main thread of the app will result in poor user experience and may get your app terminated.

If you really want to do this, though, you need to run the run loop rather than doing a busy wait.  Something like:

```
while (ftpService.isReceiving)
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

Actually, in this case where you're running the run loop yourself, you should use a different run loop mode both here and where you schedule the stream.  The default run loop mode will contain run loop sources from the rest of the frameworks and it's dangerous to let those fire from an inner run loop of your own.  Just use an arbitrary string that's likely to be unique to your program for the mode.

A run loop is a collection of various sources of events and inputs (and timers).  Both your code and various parts of the frameworks will schedule sources in the run loop.  They depend on the run loop being run in order to receive the events/inputs/timer-fires and handle them.  By not running the run loop and just busy-waiting, you were preventing the stream from receiving data from the FTP connection and handling it.

Comment: Thanks! Your code do word. But I can not understand what you want to tell me. I think I should learn more about the run loop.

Comment: Actually , this is in a second thread to load data from server. Is doing like this will lead to terrible result?

Comment: On a background thread, it is OK to block waiting for data. You can use the code I showed. (It is usually not necessary to use a separate thread because the API supports asynchronous usage, but it's OK.)  If you want to learn more about run loops, here's [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html).

Comment: what is the asynchronous usage? do you mean "performselector" ? How about if I use GCD?

Comment: Asynchronous usage is what I described in the beginning of my answer, where you don't block waiting to receive the response but rather allow the program to continue.

Comment: I find that If I use NSDefaultRunLoopMode the NSTimer will be called, otherwise, most of the time , it will not be called and the programm will stucked.

Comment: You have to schedule the timer on the run loop mode you plan to use, using `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:theTimer forMode:theMode]`. The code I gave earlier runs the run loop. It allows it to process inputs, events, and timers for sources that have been scheduled on it. If you don't run the run loop, these things can't happen. The code I gave allows it to process one input or event. It's called in a loop to allow you to check `ftpService.isReceiving` after each one. I gave a link to Apple's documentation earlier.